# SQL Display Most recent update from Junction table

Tags: sql, join

I've been doing quite a bit of research into this small query, and decided it might be time to ask the question. This will probably be a long post so I apologize for that.

This is for a school assignment, and I am simply playing around with some SQL, i'm using mySQL as the DBMS.

I am trying to display information of all members, using JOINs in an SQL statement.

Here's a brief outline of the tables i have

**Members**

- ID
- Firs_Name
- Last_name
- User_ID (Foreign Key to **Users** table)
- Membership_Type (Foreign Key to  **Membership_type** table)
- Phone
- Email
- Age

**Grade_Type**

- ID
- Description

Data in Grade_type table looks like this

```
ID  DESCRIPTION
```

---

```
 1  A Grade      
 2  B Grade      
 3  C Grade      
 4  D Grade      
 5  E Grade      
 6  F Troop
```

**Grades** (This is a junction table, which holds a member ID, a grade, and a date, to preserve a history of grade promotions and demotions.

- ID
- Member_ID (FK to **members** table
- Grade_ID (FK to **grad_type** table
- Date

Data in this table is as follows, as you can see, multiple members have changed grades 2-3 times

```
ID  MEMBER_ID  GRADE_ID  DATE
```

---

```
 1          1         3  2013-02-12  
 2          2         2  2013-03-14  
 3          4         2  2013-01-16  
 4          3         6  2013-01-29  
 5          5         1  2012-10-18  
 6          4         4  2013-04-09  
 7          6         5  2012-12-11  
 8          1         2  2013-05-03  
 9          2         3  2013-04-10  
10          3         5  2013-03-13  
11          4         3  2013-03-06  
12          5         3  2012-12-13  
13          6         4  2013-04-09  
14          1         6  2013-05-06
```

What I wish to do is have an output like this, where the grade at the end, shows the most recent change, below is also the SQL state I used to recieve this, I am struggling to figure out where, or how to put in a 'MAX(`DATE`) field or something like that.

```
ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME  PHONE      EMAIL                    AGE  USERNAME    Membership Type       ANNUAL_FEE  Grade    
 1  John        Lennon     9345 3253  jlennon@gmail.com         38  jlennon     Full Standard Member         185  C Grade  
 2  Devin       Townsend   9342 3421  dtownsend@gmail.com       78  dtownsend   Senior 70+                   135  B Grade  
 3  Mikael      Akerfeldt  9342 5675  makerfeldt@gmail.com      41  makerfeldt  Full Standard Member         185  F Troop  
 4  Dexter      Morgan     8324 3211  dmorgan@gmail.com         67  dmorgan     Social                        35  B Grade  
 5  Martin      Mendez     7845 3454  mmendez@gmail.com         82  mmendez     Senior 70+                   135  A Grade  
 6  Paul        McCartney  7543 8765  pmccartney@gmail.com      36  pmcartney   Social                        35  E Grade
```

SQL Statement

```
SELECT `members`.`ID`, `members`.`FIRST_NAME`, `members`.`LAST_NAME`,`members`.`PHONE`,`members`.`EMAIL`,`members`.`AGE`, 
`users`.`USERNAME`, `membership_type`.`DESCRIPTION` AS 'Membership Type',`membership_type`.`ANNUAL_FEE`, `grade_type`.`DESCRIPTION` AS 'Grade' FROM `2013evccor`.`members`
JOIN `users` ON `members`.`USER_ID` = `users`.`ID`
JOIN `membership_type` ON `members`.`MEMBERSHIP_TYPE` = `membership_type`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN (`grades` JOIN `grade_type` ON `grade_type`.`ID` = `grades`.`GRADE_ID`) ON `grades`.`MEMBER_ID` = `members`.`ID` GROUP BY `members`.`ID`
```

Another Statement I've tried was this, as it stands, as well as a nested statement in a JOIN

```
SELECT `grades`.`MEMBER_ID`,`grades`.`GRADE_ID`,MAX(`grades`.`DATE`) AS 'DATE' FROM `grades` GROUP BY `grades`.`MEMBER_ID`
```

However this returns this data:

```
MEMBER_ID  GRADE_ID  DATE        
---------  --------  ------------
        1         3  2013-05-06  
        2         2  2013-04-10  
        3         6  2013-03-13  
        4         2  2013-04-09  
        5         1  2012-12-13  
        6         5  2013-04-09
```

Now the dates above are the most recent dates for each member, however the grades are not correct, for example, Member_ID: 1 is now in Grade_ID: 6 as of '2013-05-06' not Grade_ID:3

Perhaps I should try using the **grades** table as the point of origin in the select statement `FROM` clause. If I did this, would I still be able to easily get a members username and membership information via the Foreign Keys in the members table?

Sorry this was a long post, I really didn't know how else to put all of this, and I like to be thorough in describing everything I've tried already.

Comment: While MySql implements GROUP BY Extensions (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html ) it does not give any guarantees that non-aggregated fields outside of GROUP BY list will have *reasonable* values.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you're saying, I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with a query on `grades` to find the date of a member's latest grade (assuming a member only has 1 grade on a given date). Then join this back to the `grades` table to filter out grades of this max date for each member.  Then use this result to join to the other tables (`grade_type` and `member`). If it is possible for members not to have grades and you want them to show up in the list anyway (without a grade), then you will need to drive the query by members and outer join to the subquery result.

```
SELECT g.member_id, t.description
  FROM grades g
  INNER JOIN ( SELECT member_id, max(dte) as dte
         FROM grades
         GROUP BY member_id
          ) m
    ON (g.member_id = m.member_id AND g.dte = m.dte)
  INNER JOIN grade_type t ON (g.grade_id = t.id)
  ORDER BY g.member_id
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works beautifully, and I was able to easily add extra information form members, as well as a couple of other tables that link to the members table.

I had to change a small part however, it didn'tlike ...ON (g.member_id = m.member_id AND g.dte = m.dte)... had to make it ...AND g.`DATE` = m.dte... Anyway, this works, thank you very much.